# How do I run Maven integration tests in alphabetical order?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.3.3 with Java 1.8.  How do I get my integration tests to run in alphabetaical order, by class name (or file, whatever's easier)?  I thought "runOrder" might help me so I created this plugin configuration ...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -noverify -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine> 
        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
        <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but as the integration tests are run, they are still not being run in order.  Notice a file beginning with "V" precedess one beginnign with "G" ...

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
Running org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.repo.VirusScanQueueDaoIT
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.196 sec - in org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.repo.VirusScanQueueDaoIT
Running org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.service.VirusScanQueueServiceIT
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 sec - in org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.service.VirusScanQueueServiceIT
Running org.mainco.subco.classroom.repo.GroupDaoIT
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.181 sec - in org.mainco.subco.classroom.repo.GroupDaoIT
Running org.mainco.subco.classroom.service.GroupServiceIT
Tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.114 sec - in org.mainco.subco.classroom.service.GroupServiceIT
Running org.mainco.subco.core.repo.CategoryDaoIT
```

Comment: Actually, it is run alphabetically... with regard to the fully qualified name (check the packages).

Comment: If you need a particular order you should use TestNG instead of JUnit where you can define dependencies between the tests which gives you the opportunity to define a particular ord.er

Answer (score 1):

The ITs are run with respect to the alphabetical order... of the [fully qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) of the class. The following list

```
org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.repo.VirusScanQueueDaoIT
org.mainco.subco.antivirus.queue.service.VirusScanQueueServiceIT
org.mainco.subco.classroom.repo.GroupDaoIT
org.mainco.subco.classroom.service.GroupServiceIT
org.mainco.subco.core.repo.CategoryDaoIT
```

follows this ordering. There are currently no [run orders](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#runOrder) working with just the class name.